# Can someone explain this phenomena?

Tags: zoology, sociality

So many parakeets sitting on a tree with no leaves ?[image]

Comment: What is your question? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why are so many parakeets sitting on a tree with no leaves. ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all necessary details. Comments are only for requesting clarification. Anyway, can you add why you think this is unusual? Are all the parakeets in this area just sitting on this one tree?

Comment: Generally, birds reside on trees during evening and night but those trees do have leaves and hence birds build nests there. Are these parakeets sleeping, if yes then why on a tree with no leaves. And why is such big number ? Is this a specific kind of behaviour ?

Comment: Shubhanshu, as I said, please [edit] your question to address these points. Comments are not indexed and hence not searchable. They can also easily go unnoticed. Therefore comments are used only for temporary purposes. A post should be self-sufficient.

Comment: phenomenon —  singular. phenomena is the plural

Answer (score 2):

Parakeets are social animals that live in large groups (flocks). Under ideal environmental conditions, they can form flocks composed of thousands of birds. http://www.softschools.com/facts/animals/parakeet_facts/1274/

The fact that this tree is without leaves is irrelevant to the Parakeets. They may or may not have caused it. They chose the tree as a place to relax. It could have been any other convenient place though. If you search google images for "parakeet flock" you will see them perching on various other surfaces in a similar manner